# ASP.NET Keep uploaded file name

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I want to keep the uploaded file name to make it possible to users to download the file under the same name. But how can I implement it? The one option I see is to store each file to folder with unique name (GUID, for example). Any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `GUID` is better option but we normally use in office `DateTime`

Answer (score 5):

When a file is uploaded you can extract its name:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        // Get the filename of the uploaded file
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var savedFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // TODO: Associate the fileName with the savedFilename
        // and probably the currently connected user in the database

        // Save the file inside the Uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), savedFilename);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You could store the file on disk under some unique name (a GUID is a good option) and then associate this unique name with the actual filename and the user so that later when he wants to download the file you would have the mapping.

Comment: This is not his question; for example if someone upload file with file name abc.jpg and other user also upload the same file name, then it will be problem

Comment: again you have edited your answer and I think you again misunderstood the question. what he want is, if user upload file with the name abc.jpg and after that if want to download he will use the same name.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar, because we have associated the original filename with the actual filename stored on the server inside the database the application could generate a link using the original filename and this link would send a request to a controller action which would serve the file. So the user would see the original filename on the page when he wants to download. But downloading the file is another part.